# Matching JSON to C# class, coordinates structure

Tags: c#, json, structure

I am having trouble translating the json formating to a c# object because of the 3 or 4 array's. Here is the relevant json part that I can't seem to translate.

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    [151165.781300000846386, 202858.609400000423193],
                    [151187.015600003302097, 202873.359400000423193],
                    [151188.046899996697903, 202874.078099999576807],
                    [151220.828100003302097, 202896.875],
                    [151191.5625, 203005.656300000846386],
                    [151223.546899996697903, 203030.593800000846386],
                    [151226.468800000846386, 203029.5],
                    [151249.453100003302097, 203047.015599999576807],
                    [151281.421899996697903, 203009.296900000423193]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried it with the following code:

```
public class geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public List<List<double[]>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public List<List<string[]>> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public double[][] coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public string[][] coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class geometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }

    public List<coordinates> coordinates { get; set; }
}
public class coordinates 
{
    List<string> subcoordinates` { get; set; }
}
```

I honestly don't know why they structured it this way. Seems unnecessary to me or is there a reason why it is implement this way because they are coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json structure indicates multi level nested arrays of coordinates - each time you see a something enclosed in square brackets (`[...]`) it's an array.

Your `coordinates` property contains an 4 level nested array - so it can be deserialized into this c# class:

```
public class Geometry
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("coordinates")]
    public List<List<List<List<double>>>> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, is this List<List<List<List<double>>>> construct not really memory intensive? Isn't this possible with primitive arrays?

Comment: @ChristiaanNieuwlaat yes, this could be done using arrays, but I don't think there should be a noticeable difference in performance. an arrays version would be `double[][][][]` - a 4 levels jagged array.

Comment: Just tried it, it works for me. Thanks for the help. Any idea why anyone would structure their JSON like that. Wouldn't 2 arrays be enough?

Comment: Glad to help :-) I have no clue why would someone want so many nesting levels.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Liked your solution, but want to know why you used `JSonProperty("")` attribute. I believe you don't need attribute here, if properties have same name

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar force of habbit. I use it any time I want my class json serlaizable, just to be able to detach the json property name from the c# property name. Most of the time when you use automatic tools to convert json to c# you get that for free anyway.